# The event can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= dotnetstandard 2.1

Tags: .net, c#-8.0, .net-standard-2.1

I'm using dot net standard 2.1 and c# 8, I want to create an event for my class (interface), I follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/#events)  and I wrote an interface:

```
using System;
using Crawler.Paging;

namespace Crawler
{
    public interface ICrawler
    {
        public event EventHandler NextPage;
        protected virtual void OnNextPage(EventArgs e)
        {

            EventHandler handler = NextPage;
            handler?.Invoke(this,e);
        }
        void Paging(IPaging paging);
    }
}
```

but take me an error:

> Error The event 'ICrawler.NextPage' can only appear on the left hand
> side of += or -=

I proceeded with this training, so where is the problem?

Comment: Tutorial uses `class`, you've declared an `interface`. C#8 has default interface methods, but I don't think that it's valid in your case

Comment: exactly an interface cannot have an implementation

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI C#8 has default interface methods, but I don't think that's an OP case

Comment: But in c# 8 we can create an interface with default implement  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods

Comment: @sda2584541 Please, check the [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796545/event-inheritance-with-c8-default-interface-implementation-traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796545/event-inheritance-with-c8-default-interface-implementation-traits) question and github issue [2928](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2928). It seems to be an exactly your case

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, yeah event only work on the classes! not the default Interface Method (DIM). thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Reason

A simple event definition ending with `;` in a class is made of 2 parts, which are the event, which only contains both add/remove accessors (methods), and the handler delegate.

for

```cs
class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler Bar;
}
```

equals to

```cs
class Foo
{
    //The event
    public event EventHandler Bar
    {
        add => _bar += value;
        remove => _bar -= value;
    }

    //The handler value
    private EventHandler _bar;
}
```

Note that the backing field is always `private`, regardless of the access modifier of the event definition. So `Bar?.Invoke()` is actually accessing the handler delegate directly, not the accessors, and can only be done within the class itself.

But a simple event definition ending with `;` in an interface is only the abstract event, which only contains both add/remove abstract accessors (abstract methods).

for

```cs
interface IFoo
{
    event EventHandler Bar;
}
```

equals to

```cs
interface IFoo
{
    public abstract EventHandler Bar;
    //The following syntax is invalid but shows how it works.
    /*
    event EventHandler Bar
    {
        abstract add;
        abstract remove;
    }
    */
}
```

The default interface implementation feature in C# does not breaking-change it, for an interface cannot contain any field (which defines what interface in C# is). As long as the handler delegate does not exist, it is not possible to access it directly, therefore `Bar?.Invoke()` is invalid.

## Solution

There is a workaround by using a manually implemented event (which is also a default implementation) with an abstract property as the handler delegate:

```cs
interface IFoo
{
    protected EventHandler BarHandler { get; set; }

    event EventHandler Bar
    {
        add => BarHandler += value;
        remove => BarHandler -= value;
    }
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    EventHandler IFoo.BarHandler { get; set; }
}
```

So that somewhere else in a default method implementation could invoke the event:

```cs
var handler = BarHandler;
handler?.Invoke(this, e);
```

Comment: thank you very much, interface nice solution.